# Question about a group defined on rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $f : R \to R^{\times}$ such that $f(x+y) = f(x)f(y)$ for all $x,y \in R.$ Define the following group $G =R \times R$ such that $$(x,y)(x', y') = (x+x', y + f(x)y').$$

This group is clearly a non abelian group in general. So my hunch is that this group can be embedded in a matrix group for nice enough $f$ because of the following similarity  :

Let $R$ be a field and $f$ be a surjective map onto $R^{\times}$ then the elements  $$\begin{pmatrix}
    f(x) & y\\
    0 & 1\\
  \end{pmatrix}$$
of the form a group under matrix multiplication which is similar to the above group.

The problem with $G$ to do similar thing, in the definition of group operation there is $f$ occuring which looks difficult to incorporate to the matrix multiplication.

What do we know about the group $G$?

(I am not sure if this group is a particular case of some well known group).

Answer (score 1):

First off, there's a general notion of [semidirect product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product) into which your group fits. Given a group $G$, and an action of $G$ on another group $A$ given by a homomorphism $\phi: G \to \mathrm{Aut}(A)$, one can construct the semidirect product $G \ltimes A$ whose underlying set is the same as that for $G \times A$, and where elements are multiplied according to the rule

$$(g, a) \cdot (h, b) = (gh, a\phi(g)(b)).$$
In your example, both $G$ and $A$ are given by the underlying additive group of $R$, and $\phi: R \to \mathrm{Aut}(R)$ takes $x$ to the automorphism $y \mapsto f(x)y$.

There's an awful lot of literature on this construction, but I'll just say a couple of things. (1) The group of affine transformations $f: R \to R$, where elements of the group are functions of the form $f(x) = mx + b$ for $m \in R^\times$ and where the group multiplication is given by functional composition, is a famous example which can be generalized considerably. (2) Semidirect products naturally give exact sequences of groups

$$1 \to A \to G \ltimes A \to G \to 1$$
and conversely, given an exact sequence $1 \to A \to H \to G \to 1$ of groups together with a splitting $i: G \to H$ of the epimorphism $H \to G$, the group $H$ can be construed as (isomorphic to) a semidirect product with $G$ acting on $A$, via the action $\phi: G \to \mathrm{Aut}(A)$ which takes an element $g \in G$ to the automorphism $\phi(g)$ on $A$ given by $a \mapsto i(g)\cdot a \cdot i(g)^{-1}$ (that last element belongs to $A$ because the exact sequence exhibits $A$ as a normal subgroup of $H$).

You need $f$ to be *injective*, not surjective, for your description to give an *embedding* into the group of invertible $2 \times 2$ matrices. But anyway, you've hit upon a fairly fundamental sort of construction.

Comment: Why the downvote?